# Dynamically set URL of web service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

Scenario: I'm running code on the client that connects to a server and uses a web service to retrieve data about a SharePoint list. I'm using the Visual Studio 2010 "service reference" to get a web service for my SP Site and get my data from the list. It works. Now how do I go about coding it such that when I want to move from Test to Production, my web service calls will still work? Note that the web service is a SharePoint web service, I did not write it. I am only using it. Is what I am suggesting possible? I do have the ability to ensure that the Site is the exact same (except for URLS) on both environments (e.g. backup the SP site and put it on production). Thanks for any suggestions.

**Summary:**

Basically I'm looking for the best way to go from test to production without re-compiling my code which consumes the SP web service. Also, as a side note, if anyone knows how similar the test/production sharepoint sites have to be, [in order for the web service to work on both without anything but the URL being changed].. that would be helpful info.

**Solution**

The project configuration file can be used to specify the web service location. The .svcdatamap and other files in the VS project are for design time use only, and the URL which is actually used to connect to the SharePoint web service is passed as an argument to the `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext` object. This is only tangentially related, but to create your own WCF web service see this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/wsdldynamicurl.aspx). BTW, the web service will work without recompilation anywhere the SharePoint List has the same List name and the column you're querying has the same name.

Comment: What type of client application is that? A windows/console app or a web application? I assume the client is running outside of the SharePoint environment, correct?

Comment: @Vassili - Yes, the client is running outside the SharePoint environment and connecting to SharePoint via the web service. The context is that it is a MSFT Office solution - e.g. code running along with a Word document.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, Visual Studio Tools for Office projects allow you to have an app.config file in your project. I'd expect that Visual Studio created the app.config file and added the necessary configuration settings related to the web service reference. In any case, you need to store the correct web service url somewhere - app.config, registry or even a database.

If you are not able to store the web service endpoint address information in the app.config file, there's a way to configure the proxy manually.

1. If it's a .asmx reference added as a legacy "Web Reference" in Visual Studio then all you need to do is set the Url property value of the proxy object before you call any web service methods. For example:

   ```
   MyASMXWebService proxy = new MyASMXWebService();
   proxy.Url = "web service url";
   proxy.HelloWorld();
   ```
2. If it's a .svc WCF service reference then things get a bit more complicated. You'll need to create your web service endpoint programmatically. For example:

   ```
   BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
   EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("web service url");

   ChannelFactory<IMyWCFWebService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyWCFWebService>(binding, endpoint);
   IMyWCFWebService proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

   proxy.DoWork();
   ```

Comment: #2 is the case here - I'm using the VS 2010 Service Reference, not the legacy web reference. Considering the info you've given me, I take it that to avoid hardcoding the URL and re-compilation, I'd need to have a settings file where my EndpointAddress URL is stored.

Comment: Yes, you can get away with only storing the web service url as long as you properly configure the binding and the rest of the endpoint attributes in the code.

Comment: As far as I know, the only file from the Service References folder that is compiled into the assembly is the Reference.cs. Any other auto-generated files, including the .svcmap file are for Visual Studio design-time use only. The web service proxy loads the endpoint information from the config file so there has to be one of those in your project if you are able to make web service calls in your development environment.

Comment: Thanks Vassili. The root of my confusion were those config files that are only for VS design time use. The only URL that the web service *actually* uses is the one used when I make a new DataServiceContext object.

Comment: @VassiliAltynikov What if the case is #1, but there isn't property named Url?

Answer (score 1):

Since SharePoint services (SVC) do not provide a proxy, option 2 will not work.  References to both locations must be included in your application and then use a parm to differentiate production from test.  I believe 2013 will likely correct this bug.

Comment: Actually option #2 in the accepted answer definitely does work, because I tested it. I'm not a SharePoint, C#, or ASP.NET developer anymore so I no longer use Visual Studio, but I took @Vassili Altynikov advice at the time this was posted and what he said does work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the URL in your project's web.config

Comment: Huh? There is no web.config. The client is not running in a SharePoint environment. The only config file in my VS project where I've found a URL had ".map" in its extension, and was created when I added a "Service reference" in VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Simple SharePoint example:

```
MyService.ListsSoapClient client = new MyService.ListsSoapClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = "site url"+"/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
```